# SQL Server Error 7904 | Find the missing File row

Tags: sql-server

DBCC checkdb reports a filestream corruption and MS says it cannot be fixed and backup is the only solution else contact support. this is a lower environment, so we just want to delete that row which have this problem.

Is there a way to identify from which row this file is missing from the table?

I was able to identify table, column.
there are no extra partitions and slot id is 37 and then I have a page id (1:1578278)

Comment: What's the full error message? "Is there a way to identify from which row this file is missing from the table?" I thought that's what you did on the very next line?

Comment: i wanted to identify the exact file that was missing. i don't know how to get that information from page id.

full error is something like 

Msg 7904. level 16, state 2, line 1
Table error: cannot find the FILESTREAM file "some alphanumeric numbers" for column id 8 (column directory id some alphanumeric numbers container id 65537) in object id 12055xxxxx, index id 1, partition id 720575xxxxxxxxxx, page id (1:1578278), slot id 37.

Comment: Use `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations` to view raw data https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/10/19/sql-server-new-way-to-use-dbcc-page-in-sql-server-2019/